# org mode does not export broken links

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When I export an org document to html, the broken links are visible as html link 'nil'.

What I want is just normal text, not link (just description from link). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can do that with an [export filter](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html).

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that you can do what you want: the description does not appear in the output for a broken link, so a filter won't help.

Comment: I'm think that something has changed in org-mode. Because in prev version broken links were visible - they were just broken but the text was visible. Now it's just 'nil'.